# 2-tuple Vector Space: GF(2)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = F^2$ for a field $F$. For $(a_1,a_2) \in V$ and $c \in F$, define $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1+2b_1,a_2+3b_2)$ and $c(a_1,a_2)=(ca_1,ca_2)$. Is $V$ a vector space over $F$ given these operations?

My approach was to attempt to demonstrate that there does not exist a unique zero, and so this is not a vector space:

$(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1+2b_1,a_2+3b_2)$

$b_1=-a_1$,
$b_2=-a_2$

$(a_1,a_2)+(-a_1,-a_2)=(a_1+2(-a_1), a_2+3(-a_2))=\bf{(-a_1,-2a_2)}$

$a_1=-b_1$,
$a_2=-b_2$

$(-b_1,-b_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(-b_1+2b_1,-b2+3b_2)=\bf{(b_1,2b_2)}$

$F^2$ isn't $GF(2)$ according to my professor's notation. He uses $\mathbb{F}_2$ to denote the finite field of two elements. $F^2$ is just $F\times F$, a 2-tuple.

Thank you, @user1551, for your help with this problem.

Comment: Do the vectors form an abelian group under addition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Actually $V$ has **no** zero elements. Show that there does not exist $(a_1,a_2)\in V$ such that $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(b_1,b_2)$ for all $(b_1,b_2)\in V$. Alternatively, by definition, the addition operation in a vector space must be commutative. Show that the given one is not.

Comment: How is my approach invalid? Just curious...

Comment: @Trancot I haven't said that your approach is invalid, but so far, you have only shown that if $u=(a_1,a_2)$ and $v=(b_1,b_2)=(-a_1,-a_2)$, you can write $u+v$ in terms of the $a_i$s and $b_i$s in two equivalent expressions, and I don't see how this is related to the question of whether $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: Are there values $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(b_1,b_2)$? Let us see. Because the LHS of this equation is defined as $(a_1+2b_1,a_2+3b_2)$, then we must find a appropriate values for the following equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
a_1+2b_1 & = & b_1 \\ a_2+3b_2 & = & b_2,
\end{eqnarray}  correct?

Comment: Are not $a_1 = -b_1$ and $a_2 = -2b_2$ such values for the defined condition? What do you mean by "$\bf{no}$ zero element$\bf{s}$"?

Comment: @Trancot $(a_1,a_2)\in V$ is a zero element if $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(b_1,b_2)$ $\color{red}{\mathbf{\text{for all}}}$ $(b_1,b_2)\in V$.

Comment: What does that mean? Here is my attempt at what you mentioned as "alternatively."   In a vector space, addition is commutative, i.e., 
\begin{eqnarray}
(a_1, a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(b_1,b_2)+(a_1,a_2),
\end{eqnarray}
but this is not the case, for
\begin{eqnarray}
(b_1,b_2)+(a_1,a_2)=(b_1+2a_1,b_2+3a_2),
\end{eqnarray}
which means---provided these operations define a vector space---that
\begin{eqnarray}
(b_1+2a_1,b_2+3a_2) = (a_1+2b_1,a_2+3b_2),
\end{eqnarray}
which is only true for $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$... :-(

Comment: Is this sufficient?

Comment: What further evidence must I have to complete this argument?

Comment: @Trancot (1) You have shown that, if $(a_1,a_2)$ is a zero element, we must have $a_1=-b_1$ for all $b_1\in GF(2)$. Clearly this cannot hold. In fact, if you pick $b_1:=1-a_1$, then $a_1\neq-b_1$. Hence $V$ has no zero elements. (2) Yes, it's OK. You have shown that, if addition is commutative in $V$, we must have $a_1=b_1$ for all $a_1,b_1$ in $GF(2)$. Again, this is not true because $a_1\neq b_1$ when $a_1=0,\,b_1=1$. So, addition is not commutative in $V$ and hence $V$ (endowed with the given addition operation) is not a vector space.

Comment: Could this not be a 2-tuple vector space over a finite field of two elements, namely $\{1,0\}$? Does the question I just asked actually make any sense?

Comment: @Trancot let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8250/discussion-between-user1551-and-trancot)